# Using a variable with a path name with a space to construct a new command variable without breaking the final command?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I've read a bunch of other questions about shell quoting and spaces in file names, and the suggestions don't seem to be working in this case.

**Putting a variable with a string with an escaped space inside of another variable un-escapes the space in the final output.**

This script assembles a command from user input and hard-coded values, displays the command stored in the variable, then runs it:

```
#!/bin/bash

memory="4096"
cpus="--cpu=host --vcpus=2"
type="--os-type=linux"
variant="--os-variant=debiantesting"
graphics="--graphics spice"
network="--network bridge=vmbr0"
disk="--disk path=/dev/$chosen_vg_name/$lv_name"

#This line is the problem:
location="--cdrom /share/media/Linux\ ISO/debian11-server.iso";
 
# Run the command based on the supplied variable values:
install_cmd="virt-install -n $vm_name --memory $memory $cpus $type $variant $disk $location $graphics $network";

printf "$install_cmd\n";
$install_cmd;
exit 0;
```

I understand what is happening. The space in the file path in the `location` variable isn't getting escaped when it's added to the `install_cmd` variable, so the `virt-install` command thinks `ISO/debian11-server.iso` is an unknown argument.

I have also tried:

```
location='--cdrom /share/media/Linux ISO/debian11-server.iso';
location="--cdrom "/share/media/Linux ISO/debian11-server.iso"";
location='--cdrom /share/media/Linux\ ISO/debian11-server.iso';
location='--cdrom /share/media/Linux\\ ISO/debian11-server.iso';
location="--cdrom /share/media/Linux\\ ISO/debian11-server.iso";
```

What is the correct syntax to escape the space in the path name in the `location` variable so that it **stays escaped** when `location` is added to the variable containing the final command?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946/how-can-we-run-a-command-stored-in-a-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That:

> ```
> $install_cmd;
> ```

Is invoking the split+glob operator on the contents of `$install_cmd` and hoping the resulting words to form the expected arguments of a simple command, which hardly makes sense.

Here, you'd want either to build code in the `bash` language in parts that you concatenate and eventually tell the shell to interpret it with `eval`, which is dangerous as it can be difficult to avoid command injection vulnerabilities. Here that would have to be:

```
  memory=4096
    cpus='--cpu=host --vcpus=2'
    type='--os-type=linux'
 variant='--os-variant=debiantesting'
graphics='--graphics spice'
 network='--network bridge=vmbr0'
    disk='--disk "path=/dev/$chosen_vg_name/$lv_name"'
location='--cdrom "/share/media/Linux ISO/debian11-server.iso"'
 
install_cmd="virt-install -n $vm_name --memory $memory $cpus $type $variant $disk $location $graphics $network"
printf >&2 'Interpreting: %s\n' "$install_cmd"
eval "(PS4='Running: '; set -o xtrace; $install_cmd)"
```

(see how the `$chosen_vg_name/$lv_name` are in that case expanded upon `eval`).

Above, I added both some `Interpreting:` and `Running:` output to show what code the shell will interpret through `eval` and what resulting command is going to be run. That running will be done using some `execve("/path/to/virt-install", ["virt-install", "-n"...], environ)` system call, `bash`'s `xtrace` output however will render it as some shell code that, if interpreted by bash would result in the same system call.

---

Or build the arguments of you simple command in parts using variable types that can hold several arguments: arrays and invoke the command made of the elements of that array:

```
  memory=4096
    cpus=(--cpu=host --vcpus=2)
    type=(--os-type=linux)
 variant=(--os-variant=debiantesting)
graphics=(--graphics spice)
 network=(--network bridge=vmbr0)
    disk=(--disk "path=/dev/$chosen_vg_name/$lv_name")
location=(--cdrom '/share/media/Linux ISO/debian11-server.iso')
 
install_cmd=(
  virt-install -n "$vm_name" --memory "$memory"
  "${cpus[@]}" "${type[@]}" "${variant[@]}" "${disk[@]}"
  "${location[@]}" "${graphics[@]}" "${network[@]}"
)

(PS4='Running: '; set -o xtrace; "${install_cmd[@]}")
```

(there, the `$chosen_vg_name/$lv_name` are expanded upon assignment to the `$disk` array).

Also remember the first argument for `printf` is the *format*. It shouldn't contain variable data.

There's there is no double interpretation of shell code, which avoids the risk of command injection vulnerabilities and is therefore preferable.